# ffmpeg video filter with RGB

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need filter mp4 video with ffmpeg using RGB values. 
For example with opengl it look like this

```
void main() {
        vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);
        float colorR = (1.0 - color.r) / 2.0;
        float colorG = (1.0 - color.g) / 2.0;
        float colorB = (1.0 - color.b) / 2.0;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(colorR, colorG, colorB, color.a);
    }
```

Can i do it with ffmpeg command ?

Comment: Do you want to process an exiting RGB-format MP4 or create one? The latter will require ffmpeg compiled with libx264rgb.

Comment: I whant ro create new video from old mp4 with diferent rgb s

Answer (score 1):

If your ffmpeg is compiled with libx264, you can use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf extractplanes=r -c:v libx264rgb -pix_fmt rgb24 output.mp4
```

You can also specify `bgr24` or `bgr0` (32-bit; has an unused 4th channel)

Comment: I checked ffmpeg is not compiled with libx264rgb but if it will how can i set RGB values ?
I need something like this ffmpeg -i input.mp4 filter_complex lutrgb="r=val:g=0:b=0" output.mp4
but this command not working.

Comment: I should clarify, if you have x264 compiled, x264rgb is included. If you just want to extract `r` values, see added command.